# Align= "center" effect on data shown gridview rows

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, alignment

I am facing a weird situation, I am developing an asp.net website, and I added a gridview control, it is placed inside  td tag.

When I ran the website online, I noticed that the data shown on the rows are shifted to the left while their header tags are centered, so I gave the td an `align="center"` property, trying to make the data  show centered in each column, and that worked perfectly when debugging the site offline.

However, when I ran the site online (after upload), the data still showed shifted (or aligned left).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<AlternatingRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

Comment: i already tried it before :S sadly for some weird reason it is only affecting the alternating rows..(on html check, the table generated to show the grid view has its alternating tr tags with align=center,while the normal tr tags without it, causing a mis-shift

Comment: oops my mistake,i was using horizontallaign instead of row style horizontalalign :)

Answer (score 4):

Set this property in the gridview: `RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the HTML source in your browser. If you see the align="center" in the offline but not in the online version, something went wrong when publishing your web page (or your browser cache needs to be cleaned, see Crimson's answer).

Comment: Html source showed the align="center" (on the online files :S)

Comment: +1 for suggestions(thx pretty helpful for future testing :) ),and i guess align=center tag on a td ..doesnt enforce itself on the gridview, so i used the property suggested above ..

Answer (score 0):

1) Do an MD5 of the uploaded files to see if the upload did go through correctly

and,

2) Refresh your browser's cache

Comment: MD5 check shows they r the same files, and i used 3 different browsers till now + empty cache, and firebug to check the code..

Comment: +1 for suggestions(thx pretty helpful for future testing :) ),and i guess align=center tag on a td ..doesnt enforce itself on the gridview, so i used the property suggested above ..